# Target parameter in the download_story item () method of the instaloader module

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram

I'm making an application to download features that are on Instagram and I'm making a function to download Instagram stories

in the instaloader documentation they write :

download_storyitem(item, target)

Download one user story.

Parameters
item (StoryItem) – Story item, as in story[‘items’] for story in get_stories()

target (Union[str, Path]) – Replacement for {target} in dirname_pattern and filename_pattern

and this is my code :

```
def get_stories(self):
        get = root.get_stories(userids=6328186396)
        root.download_storyitem(get, ['file_name.jpg', "C:\Users"])
```

but this produces an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "instagram_downloader.py", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "instagram_downloader.py", line 59, in main
    start.get_stories()
  File "instagram_downloader.py", line 21, in get_stories
    root.download_storyitem(get, ['file_name.jpg', "\Pictures"])
  File "C:\Users\codin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\instaloader\instaloader.py", line 631, in download_storyitem
    date_local = item.date_local
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'date_local'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
download_storyitem(item, '{}/{}'.format(highlight.owner_username, highlight.title))
```

use this code

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?